# Updating a field in an object in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this code:

```js
    const project = await Project.findOne({"code":currentUser.groupcode}); // this works

    const card = await Card.findOne({"id":req.body.id}); // this works 

    card.panel = req.body.newSection;
    card.save(); // this works

    project.cards[`${req.body.id}`].panel = req.body.newSection;
    project.save(); // this does not work
```

I'm trying to update the `panel` field in both the cards collection and projects collection.

When I log `` project.cards[`${req.body.id}`].panel ``, it is the correct value, so it is the correct routing.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `await` before your `save` statements and see if it resolves the issue.

If I have guessed your schemas correctly this is the answer:

```
const project = await Project.findOne({ code: currentUser.groupcode }).populate("cards");

const card = await Card.findOne({ id: req.body.id }); // this works

card.panel = req.body.newSection;
await card.save(); // this works

const cardIndex = project.cards.findIndex(card => card._id.toString() === req.body.id);

project.cards[cardIndex].panel = req.body.newSection;
await project.save(); // this does not work
```

Comment: Hi there, unfortunately this does not effect it.

Comment: If you need to see any more code please feel free to ask.

Comment: can you post your Project Schema plz? Is `project.cards` an array of card docs?

Answer (score 0):

Ok

I needed to add

```js
project.markModified(`cards.${req.body.id}.panel`)
```

before `project.save();`